# How can I change the TEdit default error message (NumbersOnly mode)?

Tags: delphi, edit, number-formatting

How can I change the TEdit's default error message when I use it in [NumbersOnly](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/StdCtrls.TEdit.NumbersOnly) mode. I mean this error:

> Unacceptable character You can only type a number here

Is it possible to change this message ?

Comment: As Nat wrote, this message seems to originate from the OS, not from the VCL. This doesn't mean you won't be able to catch it, but I noticed this on the doc: "Note, however, that a user can paste non-numeric characters in the textfield even when this property is set" so you might want to switch it for a better "numbers only edit" component anyway...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know a direct way to change the value of that message (which is handled by Windows)  but you can show your own message and then avoid to show the original windows hint ballon, using the [`Abort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.Abort) procedure in the [`OnKeyPress`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.OnKeyPress) Event.

Check this sample

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not (CharInSet(Key,['0'..'9',#8,#9]))  then      
  begin
    ShowHintMessage('Only numbers please');//you must write this function 
    Abort;//this will prevent which the original windows hint was shown
  end;
end;
```

You must we aware which this code will be prevent the execution of the clipboard operations over the control.

Update

I Update the code to allow the Tab(#9) and Back space(#8) chars.

Comment: CTRL+V is going to defeat this quite easily.

Comment: @David, maybe you misunderstand my answer, the code is for be used together with the `NumbersOnly` property. not for validate integer alone.

Comment: surely a paste will bypass this code though and end at windows default

Comment: @David the code works even with Ctrl+V, because when you press this key combination the `OnKeypress` receives a #16 char which is not inside of the allowed chars, so a call to the Abort method is made.

Comment: @RRUZ In other words your proposed solution blocks pasting?!

Comment: @Davud, Unfortunelly Yes. The code will prevent the execution of any clipboard operation, so I edit my answer to add this.

Comment: You might want to change that set into `['0'..'9', #8, #9, #13, #27, #127, '-']`.

Comment: yeah david ... u right ,,, its a bug in this code . if i change it to ['0'..'9', #8, #9, #13, #27, #127, '-'] is it works properly ?

Comment: #8 and #9 are tab and backspace ,,,, what is 13 , 27 , 127 ? and why we use '-' ? what happened if i don't use '-' ?

Comment: @Arash - the numbers introduced by the `#` are in Delphi chars represented by its decimal value from the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). So `#13` means Enter _key_; `#27` and `#127` are Escape and Delete _keys_. And if you remove the `-` _key_ from the set, you won't get the _error_ message when you press it.

Comment: thanks for your useful answer daemon . but i cant understand why i should let user to use '-' . why user need it ? i need only numbers . maybe enter and delete and backspace and tab and escape will helpful but why '-' ?

Comment: @Arash - because of negative values ;) If you don't want them just omit the '-'

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the VCL source, it looks like that message is generated by windows, rather than by Delphi. That is, the VCL is only wrapping the functionality that exists in windows. So it doesn't appear that it would be easy to modify the message.